# Infer typeof nested function based on callback

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that would accept an object and return a nested function, which would accept a callback and return the same type of function. Unfortunately I'm not able to write it in such a way, so that the result would have the same type as the callback

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T


export type Settings = {
   maxCalls: number
   interval: number
   errors: Constructor<Error>[]
}

export function withRetryDelayed<R, U extends any[]>({
   maxCalls = 2,
   interval = 100,
   errors = [Error]
}: Partial<Settings> = {}): (cb: (...args: U) => Promise<R>) => (...args: U) => Promise<R> {
   let calls = maxCalls
   return (callback: (...args: U) => Promise<R>): (...args: U) => Promise<R> => {
      const retrying = async (...args: U): Promise<R> => {
         try {
            return await callback(...args)
         } catch (err) {
            if (calls-- <= 1 || !errors.some(ErrorConstructor => err instanceof ErrorConstructor)) {
               throw err
            }
            return interval
               ? new Promise(resolve => {
                  setTimeout(() => resolve(retrying(...args)), (maxCalls - calls) * interval)
               })
               : retrying(...args)
         }
      }
      return retrying
   }
}

const theX = (a: string): Promise<string> => Promise.resolve(a)

class MockError1 extends Error { }



const withRetryCallback = withRetryDelayed({
   maxCalls: 10,
   errors: [MockError1]
})(theX)


// typeof withRetryCallback is (...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#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-BRqEbJbRqQWrF5oGbw2ObdDgARNCZG+hgLRaDyN3At0WVbUnp79V3urQycSoAnGbYRAAqKd1isH19wtd5517LgHzVHRn2REDe1HMDhwneloKeFYMgycQFSiRRyggAANPRaCYLhyyeQ0JRNCidGlVd+XoG871In0cKaJARgAWTgNkWxTGRBmGKAWwMKBsMkXClVKCpqlVckrHdVk9BkqoanqRpmjaSYVg-CkuB2fZjBzOw+B4vjElwTZzneWgKiIticMVBRVLk2oFKU4V9S4Hh+GENFqOxfJWQQOAqAQIhxCAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your generics at the point you apply them - on the inner function instead of the outer function. That way the function you get after applying settings is generic, and can be inferred based on the argument you provide.

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T


export type Settings = {
   maxCalls: number
   interval: number
   errors: Constructor<Error>[]
}

export function withRetryDelayed({
   maxCalls = 2,
   interval = 100,
   errors = [Error]
}: Partial<Settings> = {}) {
   let calls = maxCalls
   return <R, U extends any[]>(callback: (...args: U) => Promise<R>): (...args: U) => Promise<R> => {
      const retrying = async (...args: U): Promise<R> => {
         try {
            return await callback(...args)
         } catch (err) {
            if (calls-- <= 1 || !errors.some(ErrorConstructor => err instanceof ErrorConstructor)) {
               throw err
            }
            return interval
               ? new Promise(resolve => {
                  setTimeout(() => resolve(retrying(...args)), (maxCalls - calls) * interval)
               })
               : retrying(...args)
         }
      }
      return retrying
   }
}

const theX = (a: string): Promise<string> => Promise.resolve(a)

class MockError1 extends Error { }

const withRetryCallback = withRetryDelayed({
   maxCalls: 10,
   errors: [MockError1]
})(theX);

// Now typeof withRetryCallback is (a: string) => Promise<string>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Highly appreciated!